# LinearLayout partially overlaid over a ScrollView but not blocking touch events?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a LinearLayout with a semi transparent color overlaid over half of the ScrollView. I want the LinearLayout to block the touch events from getting through to the ScrollView when touching the intersection. I tried setting Filter touches when obscured but it has no effect.

What am I missing?

EDIT: Works fine on the device but not on the emulator.